# Кастомный словарь в Python - небольшой совет

Tags: python, классы, словари

Для исследования одной мат. идеи создаю словарь с таким поведением:
*если происходит обращение к отсутствующему ключу, то этот ключ вносится в словарь со заданным default значением.* Так вроде все работает:

```
class MyDict(dict):
    def __init__(self, start_dict, default):
        super().__init__(start_dict)
        self.__default = default

    def __missing__(self, key):
        self[key] = self.__default
        return self[key]

new_dict = MyDict({1: 1}, 1)
print(new_dict) >>> {1: 1}
print(new_dict[10]) >>> 1
print(new_dict) >>> {1: 1, 10: 1}
```

Хотелось бы, чтобы вместо постоянного default-значения передавалась некая функция set_value(), которая может зависеть от ключа, и от других параметров. И что-то запутался в передаче функции и аргументов!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Передавайте в ваш класс функцию с одним аргументом `default_factory(key)`. Внутри `self.__missing__` вызывайте её.

Всё что у вас есть внутри метода `self.__missing__` это `self` и `key`. При желании все дополнительные "аргументы" можно сделать полями `self`. Тогда `default_factory` должно получать два аргумента или больше, зависит только от вашей фантазии.

```
class MyDict(dict):
    def __init__(self, start_dict, default_factory):
        super().__init__(start_dict)
        self.__default_factory = default_factory

    def __missing__(self, key):
        self[key] = self.__default_factory(key)
        return self[key]


new_dict = MyDict({1: 1}, lambda key: f'this default value for {key}')
print(new_dict)
print(new_dict[10])
print(new_dict)
```

> ```
> $ python my_dict.py
> {1: 1}
> this default value for 10
> {1: 1, 10: 'this default value for 10'}
> ```

**P.S.** Пару слов про дизайн. Пока вы создаёте словарь, ключи по умолчанию - хорошо и весело. Потом будет худо: если вы опечатаетесь в имени ключа, никто вам не скажет про ошибку. Отлаживать такие вещи неприятно - баг в другом месте программы, где ваш словарь притворяется обычным словарём и никто не ожидает от него "волшебства". Посмотрите на [dict.setdefault](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault). Он во многих случаях решает проблему, хотя тоже не идеален.

**P.P.S.** [collections.defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) - похожий дизайн.

**P.P.P.S.** Как может выглядеть идеальный дизайн? Во-первых, не хочется чтобы ключи создавались случайно. Во-вторых, функция которая создаёт значение по-умолчанию может быть медленной, не хочется её вызывать без необходимости (это недостаток `dict.setdefault` - значение по-умолчанию вычисляется заранее, а ведь чаще всего оно не понадобится). В-третьих, значение по умолчанию может зависеть от массы данных которых нет в `self`, `key`.

Тяжеловесный код ниже решает все три задачи. Явный метод `self.set_def` гарантирует от опечаток при использовании словаря. `default_factory` не тратит время если ключ уже существует. Вы можете создавать разные `default_factory` в зависимости от контекста вызова - ей доступны любые данные:

```
class MyDict(dict):
    def __init__(self, start_dict):
        super().__init__(start_dict)

    def set_def(self, key, default_factory):
        if key not in self:
            self[key] = default_factory()
        return self[key]


new_dict = MyDict({1: 1})
print(new_dict)
print(new_dict.set_def(10, lambda: 'this default value for 10'))
print(new_dict)
```

Comment: Спасибо за развернутый ответ!!